# PHP Moving Array Item Shows Correct Array but Writes Wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, fwrite

Have a code that shifts an element of an array up one space.
URL loads:
`action?p=ArrayNumber`

```
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $index = $_GET['p'];
    $panel_dir = 'host.txt';
    $panel_data = file($panel_dir);

    $pos = $panel_data[$index];
    $panel_data[$index] = $panel_data[$index-1];
    $panel_data[$index-1] = $pos;

    $f_panel = fopen($panel_dir, "w+");
    foreach($panel_data as $panel_line) {
        fwrite($f_panel, $panel_line);
    }
    fclose($f_panel);  
}
```

How the content begins:

```
Array ( [0] => Name [1] => List [2] => Folder [3] => Host )
```

When print_r($panel_data); the array it shows up correctly:

```
Array ( [0] => Name [1] => List [2] => Host [3] => Folder )
```

When echo implode($panel_data); the array combines the moved element:

```
Name List HostFolder
```

Bcz of this(?!), it seems to write them combined instead of a new line. It does move it as desire but .. no idea where the combining is coming from.

```
Name  
List  
HostFolder
```

Comment: You can try to use this `"$array\n"` where you store the array so that it will make a newline after storing the first item.

Comment: Have you tried to use `implode("\n", $array);`, because by `default` `implode()` use `glue` string to combine elements.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco The goal is not implode tho -- the goal is to take the array and write it line by line back in to a text file.

Comment: So You can use example provide to do so. it will do what you expect.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I did the implode to show where the issue appears not what the need for solution is. Why is the array failing is my question.

Comment: May be elements does have hidden characters. Who knows. Have you strip them before to make any manipulations?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Tried ("\n", $array) and it did not change the array but when implode it combined the whole thing on fwrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `implode("\n", $array);` to write lines in to you file.

Here is the working example:

```
    $array = [
        'Name',
        'List',
        'Folder',
        'Host'
    ];
    $host = $array[3];
    $array[3] = $array[3-1];
    $array[3-1] = $host;
    echo implode("\n", $array);
```

**Result:**

```
Name
List
Host
Folder
```